# acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem is not working well when I use build_from helper in my Rails application.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-commentable

I'm using acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem with my Rails 4.0 application.

I have Notification controller:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_commentable
  # ......
end
```

Now using build_from to create a comment is not working:

```
>> n = Notification.last
  Notification Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" ORDER BY "notifications"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Notification id: 134, owner_id: 223, sender_id: 247, n_type: "SAVED_SEARCH", url: nil, content: "2219", read: false, created_at: "2015-01-02 19:52:54", updated_at: "2015-01-02 19:52:54", archived: false, short_url: "http://www.some_url.com">
>> u = User.last
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 252, email: "my@email.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$1...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, first_name: "eqbalosss", last_name: nil, created_at: "2015-01-01 20:16:52", updated_at: "2015-01-01 20:16:52", provider: nil, uid: nil>
>> Comment.build_from(n, u.id, "test")
=> #<Comment id: nil, commentable_id: 134, commentable_type: "Notification", title: nil, body: "test", subject: nil, user_id: 252, parent_id: nil, lft: nil, rgt: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> Comment.count
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments"
=> 0
```

I checked out the documentation and I have no clue what am I doing wrong? do I still have association between Comment and Notification? I assume that the gem would do that already.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok it seems I have to save results in an instance and save! it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `build_from` when are not actually saving the comment into the database; instead you're just building it based on your `User` model.

So, when you perform `Comment.count` you're querying your database and since the comment wasn't saved, it returns zero results.

You have to call either `comment.save` or `comment.save!` after building it in order to persist it to the database.

I hope it helps

Comment: Ohh ! Now I saw you already solved it. Sorry I wasn't fast enough :(